# pointers to an array of structures

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, structure

I'm trying to compare the variable dist between two nodes of my array of structures.

This is the structure:

```
struct arco{
  int u, v;
  double temp, dist; 
}arcos[MAXOASIS];
```

This is my code:

```
int compDist(const void *a, *void const *b, i, j){
  struct arco *ia = (struct arco *)a;
  struct arco *ib = (struct arco *)b;
  ia->arco[i].dist;
  ib->arco[j].dist;
  return(if(*ia > *ib)? *ia : *ib)
}
```

But it is wrong. How should it be done?

Comment: Include declaration of the structure, show us how you define that array, and let us know what exactly you are trying/asked to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
  ia->arco[i].dist;
  ib->arco[j].dist;
```

What is that supposed to do ? You probably want something like

```
return(ia->arco[i].dist > ib->arco[j].dist? ia->arco[i].dist : ia->arco[j].dist)
```

You could use some intermediate variables to make it cleaner.

**EDIT**

In light of your edit it's likely you want:

```
return (ia->dist - ib->dist);
```

Comment: I'm trying to compare the values of ith and jth dist in arcos[], give those values to the pointers, and then compare them.

Comment: @Ignacio Pochart And what are `a` and `b` ? How are you calling this function ?

Answer (score 1):

You are compairing pointer to strutcs rather then variables. I don't know your struct definition but I think you need something like:

```
return(if(ia->arco[i].dist > ib->arco[i].dist)? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of mistakes in your code,
You were initially returning a structure pointer whereas your function declaration says int.

```
 struct arco *compDist(const void *a, *void const *b, i, j){
  struct arco *ia = (struct arco *)a;
  struct arco *ib = (struct arco *)b;
  return(if(ia->arco[i].dist > ib->arco[j].dist)? *ia : *ib)
}
```

Also a comparison like

```
if(*ia > *ib)
```

is invalid, you can't just compare two structures, in c++, you could overload the '>' operator but you can't do the same in c as far as i know.

That should work but i can't guarantee it as i have no idea how you've defined your structure arco.

Answer (score 0):

arco is not a member of arco.

Instead of saying "it is wrong", post the compiler errors you are getting, and you will get better answers in return.